# who is 'this' inside an anonymous class implementation?

Tags: java, android, anonymous-class

I can't figure out what is the object that **this** is reference to inside an anonymous class method.
Two examples:

1. If i implement an anonymous implementation for onClick, e.g:

```
View.setOnClickListener(new View.onClick() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
        this.   //to which object this refers?
   }
}
```

2.If let's say i have the following interface:

```
interface  WebResponseHandler {
    public void onWebResponseFinished(String jsonString)
}
```

and inside some class I'm defining a variable that implements the above interface:

```
private onInitWebResponseHandler = new VolleyHandler.WebResponseHandler() {
    public void onWebResponseFinished(String jsonString) {
            .....
            this    // to which object this refers to?
    }
}
```

I was **surprised** that in the second  example the **this** refers to the class that
**private onInitWebResponseHandler** is part from and not refers to **onInitWebResponseHandler** directly

Comment: Dare I say, it is "this".

Comment: That doesn't look like Java syntax to me. Or what version is it?

Comment: @Bentaye, now all in Java

Comment: Note: it's bad practice to asynchronous modify instance variables. You should call other methods with the callback result

Comment: @OneCricketeer, sorry but i didn't understand you

Comment: I assume you're trying to use `this.x = y` rather than `this.something(jsonString)`?

Comment: this is the code inside the method:
`new Thread(new ParseJsonStringOnInit(new WeakReference(this),
                weakRefIOnAllScoresDataFirstFetched, jsonString)).start()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's test it:

```
public class Test {

    private String s = "Test Class";

    public void myMethod() {

        System.out.println("this.s: " + this.s);

        new Callable<String>() {
            private String s = "Callable Class";

            @Override
            public String call() {
                System.out.println("this.s: " + this.s);
                System.out.println("Test.this.s: " + Test.this.s);
                return null;
            }
        }.call();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().myMethod();
    }
}
```

It prints

```
this.s: Test Class
this.s: Callable Class
Test.this.s: Test Class
```

So the `this` in the anonymous class is the anonymous class

**EDIT:** Added `Test.this.s` as pointed out by **Angel Koh**

Comment: i understand your example and still surprise from the result in my case. Can you please refer to both examples in my post?

Comment: @Bentaye, also if you want to access Test's "s" parameter inside the callable, you can use Test.this.s

Comment: @AngelKoh Nice, I didn't even know about this, I added it to the answer

Comment: @Eitanos30 In your first example, this should be the anonymous `OnClickListener`
in your second example, it should be `onInitWebResponseHandler` as it is the class the this is used in

Comment: @Bentaye, thanks so maybe in Kotlin because of the lambda expression it is different. I will approve your answer and ask a new question as Kotlin issue

Answer (score 2):

with regards to your second question.
"This" refers to the innermost object.

The results will be

```
HelloWorld@6d06d69c helloWorld
1: HelloWorld$VolleyHandler@7852e922 volley
2: HelloWorld$1@4e25154f anon
3: HelloWorld$2@70dea4e anon2
```

for the following codes

```
public class HelloWorld{
    

     String s="helloWorld";
     public static void main(String []args){
         
         HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();
         hw.run();
         hw.onInitWebResponseHandler1.onWebResponseFinished("1");
         hw.onInitWebResponseHandler2.onWebResponseFinished("2");
          
         hw.onInitWebResponseHandler3.onWebResponseFinished("3");
          
        
     }
    
     public void run(){
         System.out.println(this.toString()+" "+s);
         
         
     }
     
     interface WebResposeHandler {
         public void onWebResponseFinished(String jsonString);
     }   
     
      

    class VolleyHandler implements  WebResposeHandler {
         String s="volley";
         public void onWebResponseFinished(String jsonString){
             System.out.println("1: "+this.toString() +" "+ this.s);
         }
     }  
     
     WebResposeHandler onInitWebResponseHandler1 = new VolleyHandler();
     WebResposeHandler onInitWebResponseHandler2 = new WebResposeHandler(){
         String s="anon";
         public void onWebResponseFinished(String jsonString){
             System.out.println("2: "+this.toString() +" "+ this.s);
         }
     }; 
     WebResposeHandler onInitWebResponseHandler3= new WebResposeHandler(){
         String s="anon2";
         public void onWebResponseFinished(String jsonString){
             System.out.println("3: "+this.toString() +" "+ this.s);
         }
     }; 

}
```

Comment: Kog, the third line of the output isn't clear :( it's only added '1'?

Comment: The third output was from an anonymous class of the interface. you will notice that it prints "HelloWorld$1@xxxx" > because anonymous class does not have a "name", java will itemize it 1,2,3... etc  (basically 1st anon in class HelloWorld).

Comment: @Eitanos30 I have edited the codes, with 2 anon classes, for you to see the effect.